# Counting with Increments in SQL

Tags: sql, increment

I have a situation where a discount is applied to an account for a specified amount of time, and then changed back to original discount.

```
Disount    Date
  10        1/1/2013
  10        1/2/2013
  20        1/3/2013
  20        1/4/2013
  20        1/5/2013
  10        1/6/2013
  10        1/7/2013
```

I want to identify the changes by counting incrementally

```
Disount    Date       Identify
  10        1/1/2013     1
  10        1/2/2013     1
  20        1/3/2013     2
  20        1/4/2013     2 
  20        1/5/2013     2
  10        1/6/2013     3
  10        1/7/2013     3
```

I've tried:

```
DECLARE @groupercount int
SET @groupercount = 1
```

and in a case statement used:

```
when <whatever> then @groupcount
else @groupcount +1
```

This only yields a 1 or a 2 in the Identify column, it won't increment to 3, 4, 5 and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: What DBMS and version are you using?  SQL Server, mySQL, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to add up the periods where the discount is the same (based on the date).  Your syntax looks like SQL Server syntax.  The following is SQL Server 2012 syntax (and this also works in Postgres and Oracle):

```
select t.discount, t.date,
       (sum(NewPeriodStart) over (order by date)) as Identify
from (select t.*,
             (case when t.discount = lag(t.discount) over (order by date) then 0 else 1
              end) as NewPeriodStart
      from t
     ) t;
```

If you don't have `lag()` and cumulative `sum()`, you can still do this just using `row_number()` and basic window functions:

```
select discount, date, dense_rank() over (partition by groupid order by mindate) as Identify
from (select t.*, min(date) over (partition by groupid) as mindate
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (order by date) -
                    row_number() over (partition by discount order by date)
                   ) as groupid
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```